# Не работает управление прав в mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день. В данный момент читаю книгу "Линн Бейли - Изучаем SQL", раздел про привелегии. Испытываю проблемы с командами REVOKE GRANT OPTION, RESTRICT и CASCADE. Делаю все, как написано в книге, но mysql ругается.

Мои действия:

```
mysql -u root -p
******
create user test1;
create user test2;
use some_db;
grant select on some_table to test1 with grant option;
quit;
mysql -u test1
use some_db;
grant select on some_table to test2;
quit;
mysql -u root -p
******
use some_db;
revoke grant option on select on some_table from test1;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select on some_table from test1' at line 1
```

При этом команда

```
revoke select on some_table from test1
```

работает. А команда

```
revoke select on some_table from test1 cascade
```

уже не работает. То же самое с restrict. Выдает:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'restrict' at line 1

В чем может быть причина? Mysql не поддерживает эти команды? Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> читаю книгу "Линн Бейли - Изучаем SQL"

Наверняка в этой книге присутствует фраза

> Синтаксис команд может отличаться у разных СУБД. Для уточнения синтаксиса смотрите документацию на конкретную СУБД

[Документация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/revoke.html) MySQL вполне четко говорит о синтаксисе команды `REVOKE`

```
REVOKE
    priv_type [(column_list)]
      [, priv_type [(column_list)]] ...
    ON [object_type] priv_level
    FROM user [, user] ...

REVOKE ALL [PRIVILEGES], GRANT OPTION
    FROM user [, user] ..
```

Т.е. никаких модификаторов `CASCADE`, `RESTRICT` не поддерживается. И синтаксис `REVOKE GRANT` считается невалидным

Comment: Понял, спасибо.